# How to convert an array of objects to a custom object without index

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array:

```
[
  {
    "resource": "Vendas",
    "permissions": [
      "Visualizar",
      "Criar/Editar",
      "Excluir",
      "Exportar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "resource": "Consultas",
    "permissions": [
      "Visualizar",
      "Exportar"
    ]
  }
]
```

and I'm trying to make it like this:

```
{
   "Vendas":[
      "Visualizar",
      "Criar/Editar",
      "Excluir",
      "Exportar"
   ],
   "Consultas":[
      "Visualizar",
      "Exportar"
   ],
}
```

This is what I have tried to get the `resource` value into `permissions`:

```
const formattedPermissionsArr = permissionsData.map(permission => {
   return { [permission.resource]: permission.permissions };
});
```

And it kinda worked. This is the output:

```
      {
        "0":{
          "Vendas":[
             "Visualizar",
             "Criar/Editar",
             "Excluir",
             "Exportar"
          ]
       },
       "1":{
          "Consultas":[
             "Visualizar",
             "Exportar"
          ]
       }
      }
```

but I don't need the `"0"` object, how can I remove it and leave only like the sample I'm trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Array.prototype.map`, you can build the result object using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "resource": "Vendas",
    "permissions": [
      "Visualizar",
      "Criar/Editar",
      "Excluir",
      "Exportar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "resource": "Consultas",
    "permissions": [
      "Visualizar",
      "Exportar"
    ]
  }
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.resource] = cur.permissions;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Also, Unpacking fields from objects passed as a function parameter using [`Object Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data = [{"resource":"Vendas","permissions":["Visualizar","Criar/Editar","Excluir","Exportar"]},{"resource":"Consultas","permissions":["Visualizar","Exportar"]}]

const formatData = (data) => data.reduce((res, {
    resource,
    permissions
  }) =>
  //add new property with the value of `resource` as key and permissions as value
  (res[resource] = [...permissions], res), {})

console.log(formatData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: your solution also works but since Derek ansered first, I had to choose him. Thanks anyway!